# How to remove the word "FATAL" in log.fatal() in log4net. Example [2018-10-26 09:37:14,889] FATAL Log Message

Tags: log4net

How to remove the word "FATAL" in log.fatal() in log4net. Example [2018-10-26 09:37:14,889] FATAL Log Message. How to remove FATAL from this by using log4net configuration? or its a default in log.fatal()?

Comment: Why do you need `log.fatal` w/o the `FATAL` word? It will help to locate a certain log in the log file called with `log.fatal` (so there will be rows with `FATAL` and rows with `WARNING` and you would want to determine one from another). Otherwise, use different methods (if this is not the actually fatal case).

Comment: You can filter the word afterwards if you're showing somewhere the message and don't want to FATAL word to appear. But not on the `write` part, I think.

Comment: If you also want to remove INFO from log.Info messages and DEBUG from log.Debug messages etc, then you could remove %-5level or %level from the conversionPattern in your config.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by editing your configuration and removing [%level] field from the layout pattern.

```
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <threshold value="DEBUG" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="[%date]-[%thread]-**[%level]**-[%logger] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
```

Comment: This was simple but useful. Thank you.